# ifstream a file which another program is writing to?

Tags: c++, windows, file, ifstream

What happens when I try to open a file using `std::ifstream` while that file is being written to by another application?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the sharing mode used to open the file in the other program. If the open mode you use is compatible with the sharing mode, then you'll open the file. Otherwise, the open will fail. C++ doesn't really offer "sharing modes," though, so the sharing modes you get will be whatever your vendor's implementation happens to use. If you *really* want control over how you open a file, use the OS-provided functions (`CreateFile`, in this case).

As writes from the other program take effect, you'll be able to read them in your program. If you also write to the file, then your writes and the other program's writes might interfere with each other, causing data loss or jumbled output; don't do that.

Comment: Adding to Rob's answer, [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zek0beca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a non-standard constructor argument for specifying the protection mode for files opened using `basic_ifstream` and `basic_ofstream`

Comment: Do you mean to say that you can't open a file to read while another process is writing to it?  (My answer would have been more along the lines of: what difference could it possibly make?)

Comment: @James, if the other process didn't allow sharing, then no, you can't open it. That's how the *dwDesiredAccess* and *dwShareMode* parameters to [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) interact.